# What does "refactoring" mean?

Tags: c#, refactoring, theory

Can someone explain to me what "refactoring" or "to refactor" mean?

I think the subject is too broad to be covered in every detail but can someone supply a simple explanation of the term?

Comment: [Martin Fowler - Refactoring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598266/what-does-refactoring-means)

Comment: What research did you do?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I think that link is a better demo of recursion than refactoring :)

Comment: StackOverflow is for *specific questions* about *actual code*.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is best explained in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/719exd8s.aspx) itself:

> Refactoring is the process of improving your code after it has been
>   written by changing the internal structure of the code without
>   changing the external behavior of the code.

**On a side note:-**

You can do the **refactoring** when the class violates the [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 4):

Martin Fowler wrote a book on it and (at least largely) invented the term.

[His definition](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DefinitionOfRefactoring.html)

Answer (score 3):

It means reorganizing your code  to make it more readable, efficient, maintanable without introducing new bugs, not changing the behaviour and (obviously) not breaking the build

Answer (score 1):

Re-factoring in it's simple term realigning your code for better performance, readability, maintainability, extensibility while keeping the original business functionality intact.
Now what I just said was theoretical briefing and the real challenge is get it to practice. As per my understanding, code re-factoring is not rearranging code in arbitrary fashion. I rather follow a systematic approach when I take something for re-factoring. Please see [this](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring) link, which I recommend you to start and have it as checklist when you approach code re-factoring.